# Inserting text in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

i am developing a simple application in Java and i wanted to know if there is any way i can insert additional text(somewhere in the middle of a sentence) inside a textarea , which is not empty, at a position where the cursor is placed on the click of some component. Can someone please direct me how to go about getting it done

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If this is a [JTextArea component](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) you can use the `.append` method to add text to the end of the text area, or the `.insert` method to insert the new text at a specific position.

If you need to insert the text at the current caret position use the [.getCaretPosition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getCaretPosition%28%29) method

Comment: My problem is i want to insert text at the place where the cursor is placed in the textarea box and how do i get to know the exact place it is positioned in the textarea.

Answer (score 6):

```
textArea.replaceSelection(text);
```

From the API:

> Replaces the currently selected content with new content represented
>   by the given string.  If there is no selection this amounts to an
>   insert of the given text

Answer (score 5):

Check out: [`JTextComponent.getCaretPosition()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getCaretPosition%28%29).

The method `getCaretPosition()` is inherited by `JTextArea`, you can use it to get the cursor position. Then you can use [`JTextArea.insert(String str, int pos)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) to insert text at that position.

Sample:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
final JTextArea jta = new JTextArea("Hello world\nHello world\nHello world");
JButton btn = new JButton("Add");
btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int pos = jta.getCaretPosition(); //get the cursor position
        jta.insert("Some more", pos); //insert your text
    }            
});
frame.add(jta, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.add(btn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```